# Product limit with exponentials

Tags: limits, exponential-function, products

Find an explicit formula for the limit:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \prod_{k=2}^{n} (2 - e ^ {\frac 1 k})$$

I am not asking for convergence proof since I know the sequence is decreasing and bounded.

Comment: Most probably there is a mistake in the formula. Product up to n instead of infinity?

Comment: What makes you think there is an explicit formula for the limit of these quantities (once corrected)?

Comment: I don't know if there is formula, that's why I'm asking. I know the limit exists.

Comment: We all know the limit exists - and some of us would be quite surprised to see an explicit formula emerge (which makes the phrasing of your question rather odd, "Is there a formula" seeming better suited than "Find a formula").

Comment: The funny story is that the result is "close" to $\frac{\phi }{5}\sqrt{e} $ (according to RIES) !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: What is $\phi$ ?

Comment: @Przemo. This is the golden ratio $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5} 2$

Comment: @VargaRobert: This is a very interesting sequence indeed. I wonder have you figured out this example yourself or have you stated somebody else' idea? As a matter of fact I have found a explicit formula for the limit -- see my answer below. I was also wondering what happens if you replace the $1/k$ term in the product by some $1/k^\theta$ where $\theta>1$. I think in that case for the limit to be finite we have to remove the prefactor $n$ and replace it by unity.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Yes, your formula gives correct values of the first six digits . The seventh digit is already wrong.

Comment: @Przemo This is from a Quora post, someone else wrote it and I managed find approximate value of the limit, but no formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to be a very primitive attempt to answer this question. Yet I think it is worth posting since this kind of calculations appear many times in calculus. We take the log of  the limit and then we Taylor expand the following function:
\begin{equation}
\log\left(2 - e^{\frac{1}{k}}\right) = \log\left(1 - \sum\limits_{p=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p!} \frac{1}{k^p}\right) = -\frac{1}{1} \sum\limits_{p=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p!} \frac{1}{k^p} - \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{p=2}^\infty \frac{2^p-2}{p!} \frac{1}{k^p}-\frac{1}{3} \sum\limits_{p=3}^\infty \frac{3^p-3 \cdot 2^p+3}{p!} \frac{1}{k^p}-\frac{1}{4} \sum\limits_{p=4}^\infty \frac{4^p-4 \cdot 3^p+6\cdot 2^p-4}{p!} \frac{1}{k^p}-\cdots
\end{equation}
Now if we denote the unknown limit by $g$ we clearly have:
\begin{equation}
\log(g) = \log(n) + \sum\limits_{k=2}^n \log(2-e^{\frac{1}{k}}) = \log(n) - (H_n-1) - \frac{1}{1} \sum\limits_{p=2}^\infty \frac{1}{p!} (\zeta(p)-1)) - \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{p=2}^\infty \frac{2^p-2}{p!} (\zeta(p)-1) -\frac{1}{3} \sum\limits_{p=3}^\infty \frac{3^p-3 \cdot 2^p+3}{p!} (\zeta(p)-1) -\cdots
\end{equation}
Now $\log(n) - (H_n-1) \rightarrow 1 - \gamma$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$ and the remaining sums all converge . The final result is therefore:
\begin{equation}
g = \exp\left(1-\gamma - \sum\limits_{p=2}^\infty (\zeta(p)-1) \frac{1}{p!} \sum\limits_{l=1}^p \frac{1}{l} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{l-1} \binom{l}{j} (l-j)^p (-1)^j \right) = \exp\left(1-\gamma - \sum\limits_{p=2}^\infty (\zeta(p)-1) \frac{1}{p!} \sum\limits_{l=1}^p \frac{1}{l} l! S_2(p,l)\right) = \exp\left(1-\gamma - \sum\limits_{p=2}^\infty (\zeta(p)-1) \frac{1}{p!} (-1)^p Li_{1-p}(2)\right) \simeq 0.5335376801314199077153...
\end{equation}
where $S_2(p,l)$ are Stirling numbers of the second kind and $Li_n(x)$ is the polylogarithmic function.
The question remains is it possible to further simplify the result..

Note that the original sequence converges very slowly. It is only for $n> 60000000$ that $g_n < 0.53353768$. On the other hand the series in the exponential in the last formula converge very fast. I truncated the sum over $p$ at $p=150$ and I obtain an accuracy of twenty three digits.

Now, the question remains is it possible to further simplify the result. Let us take the sum in the exponential:
\begin{equation}
S = \sum\limits_{p=2}^\infty (\zeta(p)-1) \frac{(-1)^p}{p!} Li_{1-p}(2) = \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \sum\limits_{p=2}^\infty \frac{(-1/k)^p}{p!} Li_{1-p}(2) = \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \sum\limits_{p=2}^\infty \frac{(-1/k)^p}{p!}  \frac{d^{p-1}}{d \epsilon^{p-1}} \left.\left(\frac{2 e^{\epsilon}}{1-2 e^{\epsilon}}\right)\right|_{\epsilon=0} = \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \int\limits_{0}^{-1/k} \left(\frac{2 e^\xi}{1-2 e^\xi} - \frac{2}{1-2}\right) d\xi = \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \left( \log\frac{1}{2 e^{-1/k}-1} - \frac{2}{k}\right) = \sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty \left(-\log(2-e^{1/k})-\frac{1}{k}\right) = - \log(g) + \log(n) - \left(H_n-1\right)
\end{equation}
Taking the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get $S = -\log(g) + 1- \gamma$ which is equivalent to $g = \exp(1-\gamma-S)$. As we can see this was going in circles. But at least, as a sanity check, we made sure that the result is correct.

Comment: Superb for sure !

Comment: That is nice work, but maybe there is a simpler closed form.

Comment: @VargaRobert: I was trying to further simplify the sum but I just went in circles and arrived at the original limit.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to get a fairly accurate value for this product.

Using Taylor series gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\log\left(2-e^{1/n}\right)\\
&\small=-\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{n^3}-\frac{13}{12n^4}-\frac5{4n^5}-\frac{541}{360n^6}-\frac{223}{120n^7}-\frac{47293}{20160n^8}-\frac{36389}{12096n^9}
\end{align}
$$
Applying the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to this series yields
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=2}^n\log\left(2-e^{1/k}\right)\\
&\small\sim C-\log(n)+\frac1{2n}+\frac1{12n^2}+\frac1{36n^3}+\frac1{80n^4}+\frac1{300n^5}+\frac1{5040n^6}+\frac{17}{28224n^7}+\frac{829}{483840n^8}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
&\small\log\left(n\prod_{k=2}^n\left(2-e^{1/k}\right)\right)\\
&\small\sim C+\frac1{2n}+\frac1{12n^2}+\frac1{36n^3}+\frac1{80n^4}+\frac1{300n^5}+\frac1{5040n^6}+\frac{17}{28224n^7}+\frac{829}{483840n^8}
\end{align} 
$$
where $C$ is the log of the limit we seek and the next term in the series is approximately $\frac1{8000n^9}$.

Using $n=100$ yields
$$
e^C\approx0.5335376801314199077153
$$
Using $n=1000$ yields
$$
e^C\approx0.53353768013141990771530812952793
$$

Answer (score 0):

A few hints that might help you out: If the product in your expression is $P = e^{\log P}$, then you can use the property of the logarithm $\log (2-e^{\frac{1}{k}}) = \log 2 +\log (1-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{k}}}{2})$. For large $k$ the last expression is close to $-\log 2$, so you can use Taylor series for expansion.

Comment: For large $k$, $\log\left(2-e^{1/k}\right)\sim-\frac1k$, which tends to $0$, not $\log(2)$.